# Trouble understanding how to implement .map()

Tags: javascript, axios, array.prototype.map

Only a few months in to a dev program and I'm an idiot so bear with me.

I'm attempting to build a jeopardy app using http://jservice.io/. The function below first makes a get request to the URL, then uses _.sampleSize to get 6 random responses from the API, then iterates through NUM_CATEGORIES to get the ids (which are saved to the categoryID variable) before pushing those ids to the catId array. Also, please do correct me if my understanding of how that works is completely off.

```js
let catId = [];

async function getCategoryIds() {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://jservice.io/api/categories/?count=50`);
    NUM_CATEGORIES = _.sampleSize(res.data, [n = 6]);

    for (let num of NUM_CATEGORIES) {
        let categoryID = num.id;
        catId.push(categoryID);
    }
    console.log(catId);
}
getCategoryIds();
```

The next part of the project is to return an object with data about a category like so:

Returns { title: "Math", clues: clue-array }

- Where clue-array is:
- [
- ```
   {question: "Hamlet Author", answer: "Shakespeare", showing: null},
  ```
- ```
   {question: "Bell Jar Author", answer: "Plath", showing: null},
  ```
- ]

In the function below I've attempted to use .map() to iterate over the catId array and return the data I need but honestly, I'm just completely lost here (which is why I didn't bother moving on to the "clues" part). Can someone help explain to me how I can use map to make this work?

```js
async function getCategory(catId) {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://jservice.io/api/clues?category=${catId}`);
    catId.map(result => {
        return {
            question: res.data.question,
            answer: res.data.answer,
            title: res.data.title,
        }
    });
    console.log(catId);
}
```

Comment: `map` returns a new array. You can't just log `catId` and expect any changes to the original array. Either assign the result of calling `map` to a new variable, and log that, or use `forEach` which adjusts array element in place.

Comment: Yeah I guess map doesn't really work well here anyway. Went with forEach but still having trouble with implementing it

Answer (score 0):

IIRC correctly Axios returns an object with a `data` property. So you need to use `map` to iterate over `data`, and return a new object with each element's values.

```js
async function getCategory(catId) {

  const res = await axios.get(`http://jservice.io/api/clues?category=${catId}`);

  const out = res.data.map(el => {
    return {
      question: el.question,
      answer: el.answer,
      title: el.title,
    }
  });

  console.log(out);

}
```